# Adding AWGN into a positive real signal

Tags: noise, ofdm

I am trying to add a Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) to a signal whose mean is 0.5.

I am working with OFDM for Li-Fi communications whose signal must be real and positive. Normally, The AWGN is added to the signal $X$ (which represents the output of the iFFT operation, Let's consider the ACO-OFDM for this case where the negative part of the signal is removed) as following:

```
I = sum(sum(x_ifft.^2)) / (size(X,1) * size(X,2))/m; 
var  = 10^(-0.1*EbN0) * I;
sigma = sqrt(2*var);
noise = sigma * randn(size(X));
X_noise = X + noise;
```

where, $m = log_2(M)$ and $M$ is the modulation order. In the above method, we added the AWGN to the signal with assumption that `mean(X) = 0`.

I was wondering, what's about if the input/output of my iFFT has a mean of 0.5, it means for my signal $X_i$ , I have `mean(X_i)=0.5`; and the output of my iFFT is always positive real values,  How can I add the AWGN in that case?

$NP$: In case if I used the same way mentioned above; the value of `I = sum(sum(x_ifft.^2)) / (size(X,1) * size(X,2))/m;` will be almost double compared when the `mean(X) = 0`. Consequently, the sigma  will also be double leading to higher effect of the noise.

Is that effect is normal because the mean of the input/output signal became 0.5, or the way of adding the noise must be changed?

Comment: If your signal is always positive, Gaussian noise might not be the appropriate model for all cases and only useful as an approximation for large signal-to-noise ratios and then treated as a truncated Gaussian to insure positivity of S+N.

Comment: What you mean by "If your signal is always positive"? Do you mean the time-domain signal or the frequency-domain signal?   I see in this reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0057.pdf , they are using a time-domain positive, real signal with Gaussian noise.

Comment: Moreover, the above mentioned example is the added noise with ACO-OFDM whose signal is also always positive in time domain.  So I was wondering, how can I add the noise if the signal is always positive with mean 0.5.

Comment: In that paper their transmitted x(t) is >=0, but after adding the noise their received signal y(t) can be <= 0, not sure that's possible for the system they describe so I would assume its an approximation to the truth.